# How do I simulate Database throttling in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

Sometime ago I had a code question in a take home test. It was as follows:

> **Database Throttling**
>
> You are given an array **userInfo** of user data and a function **updateDB** that takes a single user data argument. **updateDB** makes an asynchronous call that parses the user data and inserts the parsed data into a database. The database throttles requests so to make sure all user data is added to the database we need a function **addAllUserData** that calls **updateDB** on each entry in **userInfo** making sure never to exceed 7 calls per second to prevent being throttled.

```
var userInfo = [{'name':'antonio', 'username':'antonio_pavicevac_ortiz'}], dataBase = [];

function updateDB(singleUserDataArgument, callback){
    dataBase.push(callback(singleUserDataArgument));
}

function addAllUserInfo(data) {
    var eachUserData;
    setInterval(function(){
      eachUserData = data.map(data)
    }, 7000);
}
```

As you can see by my attempt I am having a hard time wrapping my head around this exercise. Could anyone also inject what is meant by throttling in regards to async calls?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think the throttling has anything to do with async from an abstract perspective.  The database simply won't accept more than seven calls per second from a client, else it will presumably just drop extra requests over that seven per second limit.
So you could keep track of how many calls you make per second or just make seven calls, wait 1 second, make seven more calls, etc..

Comment: Thanks Mrogers! So with this example they are essentially inferring the throttling by expecting you to inject setInterval in some way?

Comment: I would assume that they would mark an answer down that could send more than seven requests to the database per second.  So yes you could probably accomplish that with setInterval or some other JS function.

Comment: Mrogers—Do you think you can provide a example of how one would accomplish this? What I attempted is what I thought would work but I am sure doesn't work.

Comment: the reason you're having a hard time wrapping your head around it is because you won't let go of setTimeout. setTimeout has nothing to do with counting requests per second. your current code will not allow 7 requests per second it just forces each request to wait seven seconds. hope my answer clarifies that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// contains times at which requests were made
var callTimes = []; 

function doThrottle(){
  // get the current time
  var time - new Date().getTime();

  // filter callTimes to only include requests this second
  callTimes = callTimes.filter(function(t){
    return t > time-1000;
  });

  // if there were more than 7 calls this second, do not make another one
  if(callTimes.length > 7) return true;

  else{
    // safe, do not throttle
    callTimes.push(time);
    return false;
  }
}

// use like this
function makeRequest(){
    if(doThrottle()){ /* too many requests, throttle */ }
    else{ /* it's safe, make the ajax call*/ } 
}
```